# Facebook OAuth Redirects and Custom App URL Scehem

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get Facebook to redirect back to my Unity application (running on android) after a call to https://facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth. I've created a custom URL scheme in my android app like myApp://. However, when I attempt to send the OAuth request through to facebook, it tells me that the redirect_uri is not supported. I've tried to add my custom URL to my Facebook app's OAuth settings, but it says it is not a valid URL (which makes sense, as it's technically not).

The request:

`var url = string.Format("https://facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?client_id={0}&response_type=token&redirect_uri={1}", "MYAPPID", "redfish%3A%2F%2Ffacebooklogin");`

My app's AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="sensor">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="redfish" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Code for catching the redirect in unity:

```
public class OnAcessToken : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnAccessToken(string accessToken)
    {
        Debug.Log("Received access token: " + accessToken);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("FileSelect");
    }
}
```

The class `OnAccessToken` is hit using a custom library generated by the instructions at http://oferei.com/2013/06/serverless-instagram-authentication/.

What I'm asking is how to I get Facebook to allow my custom URL scheme as a valid redirect_uri? Or am I going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up answering my own question with some additional research. Using a custom URL schema for android isn't necessary, and according to Google, the practice of using something like `myApp://` is being deprecated.

Instead, my schema is now `http://myApp.auth`, and the corresponding intent filter looks like this:

```
<intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="http" 
              android:host="redfish.auth/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

Now, in Facebook's settings, I can set `http://redfish.auth` as an acceptable OAuth URL, and it won't complain since it has the `http` schema. This overrides the host rather than the schema, so it works in Chromium browsers (previously did not because of the aforementioned Chrome standards).

So, when I make a call to `http://redfish.auth/facebooklogin`, it redirects back to my app!

References: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: I liked your solution but it doesn't work for me, perhaps because I'm testing on a phone with Samsung's default net browser app rather than Chrome? The browser interprets http://myapp.auth as a web address, and returns 'myapp.auth's DNS address could not be found'. This is despite having put http as scheme in the intent filter in manifest file. So either this method works only with certain browsers or I'm doing something wrong